# Where can I find a copy of Moussatat's 1976 thesis "On the Asymptotic Theory of Statistical Experiments and Some of Its Applications"?

Tags: reference-request, st.statistics

It was apparently written at Berkeley under the direction of Le Cam, and it is cited in a number of contributions to mathematical statistics, for example in Strasser's (1985) book "Mathematical Theory of Statistics". There Strasser states on page 130 that he follows Moussatat's proofs (of a theorem of Wald). Since I don't understand Strasser's proof on pages 131-132, I would like to have a look at the original, but could not find it anywhere so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with most US dissertations, Proquest has it: http://search.proquest.com/docview/302793918

If your institution doesn't have an appropriate subscription, they will sell you a copy (in various formats) for USD 38.00 and up.

Comment: I would like to add that asking your librarian is a good idea. Thesis might be available via the interlibrary loan, or your university might have negotiated a reduced prices with Proquest, etc.